# MFMailComposeViewController won't close

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created an app that sends a pre-populated email. The email will send perfectly, however the mail composer will not close. below is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any)
{
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}

func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {     
    let subject = "subject"
    let body = "body"

    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["example@example.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject(subject)
    composeVC.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)

    return composeVC
}
func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

// MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        break
    case .saved:
        break
    case .sent:
        break
    case .failed:
        break
    }

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tried multiple suggestions that I have found here and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Unrelated but you should call `configuredMailComposeViewController` inside the `if` statement. Why create it if you can't send email?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to make sure is controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {     
    let subject = "subject"
    let body = "body"

    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    ....
}
```

Your `MFMailComposeViewController` lives in the `configureMainComposeViewController` function and goes out of scope once it terminates. That means your delegate also goes away.

Set your composeVC variable as an instance var and you should be fine.